# How do I check if a row of a table was insert in laravel eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Before query all the information from DB I want to check if a row of a table was insert or not and if there are no any new insert I will not use query method.But I'm much understand about how to check up if it was inserted or not in Laravel5 with Eloquent library.

I've research some tutorial I found as below **sql** sentence but I don't how to used it in Eloquent and this sql is work as my expected or not.

On checkingIfNotificationUpdated method I want to checking for true and false when a row was insert into that tables only but as this sentence it will query all data

```
   public function checkingIfNotificationUpdated(){

//       SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.'.$this->table.' WHERE DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) < UPDATE_TIME
         RETURN self::select('*')->where(DB::raw('DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)'),'<','UPADTE_TIME')->get();
    }
```

Here is my query method within checking Notification table is insert or not

```
  public function getNotification($user_id, $gId)
    {
        if($this->checkingIfNotificationInserted()  == true){
            $this->_data = self::select('*')->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'n_user_id')
                ->where('n_group_code_id','=', $gId)
                ->get();
            if (count($this->_data)) {
                return $this->_data;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            // to go with old data.
        }

    }
```

Here is data my respond data when Used dd()

```
Collection {#619 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => Notification {#620 ▼
      #table: "notification"
      +timestamps: true
      -_data: false
      #connection: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      #attributes: array:11 [▼
        "n_id" => 269
        "n_user_id" => 69
        "n_group_code_id" => 11
        "n_source_id" => 231
        "n_activity_type" => "Issue Till"
        "n_create_times" => "2016-04-06 09:04:40"
        "n_description" => "Issue Till"
        "n_status" => 0
        "url" => "teller/trans_issues"
        "updated_at" => "2016-04-06 09:45:40"
        "created_at" => "2016-04-06 09:45:40"
      ]
      #original: array:11 [▼
        "n_id" => 269
        "n_user_id" => 69
        "n_group_code_id" => 11
        "n_source_id" => 231
        "n_activity_type" => "Issue Till"
        "n_create_times" => "2016-04-06 09:04:40"
        "n_description" => "Issue Till"
        "n_status" => 0
        "url" => "teller/trans_issues"
        "updated_at" => "2016-04-06 09:45:40"
        "created_at" => "2016-04-06 09:45:40"
      ]
      #relations: []
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #appends: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▼
        0 => "*"
      ]
      #dates: []
      #casts: []
      #touches: []
      #observables: []
      #with: []
      #morphClass: null
      +exists: true
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you can check with your input fields when you inserted:
 Here,

in Controller :

```
     $input = $request->all();

    //check input value if exists or not in db...

     $b_exists = ModelClass::where('title','=',$input['title'])->exists();

     if($b_exists){
     //show message: alteady exists
     }
     else{
     //
     ....new data inserted 
    }
```

Comment: I think so but not yet as my concern

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Eloquent there is no need to query back to the DB.

Assume you do an insert like this:

```
$myModel = ModelClass::create($params);
```

or this:

```
$myModel = new ModelClass($params);
$myModel->save();
```

You can then do this check:

```
if (! empty($myModel->id)) {
    // Model has been successfully inserted
}
```

Comment: My method don't related with insert sentence it will do by another function or controller I just want to check when Notification table was inserted by another human or not and if so I will query data to client. and some of this controller don't used eloquent.

Comment: Is it possible if I try to used this build method
    public function checkingIfNotificationInserted() {

        $id = self::getQueueableId();
        return $id;
    }

Comment: If some of the controllers don't use eloquent then switch them, either use eloquent everywhere or not at all. If you do that then you could use an event handler. The laravel docs cover the events that are fired when eloquent does an insert but those same events aren't triggered if you use raw db inserts.

Comment: How to used that event?